# MS SQL SERVER (Ubuntu 16.04.2) Требования

Tags: c#, ubuntu, sql-server, entity-framework, .net-core

Здравствуйте! 
Есть некоторый чат-бот(написан на `c#` с использованием `.net core` и `Entity Framework Core`.), который использует в качестве бд `MS SQL` на `MS SQL Server`.

Недавно решил залить его на сервер (2.2ГГц, 0.5 RAM, 10 gb hdd), чтобы он не зависел от состояния моего пк и **столкнулся с проблемой при установке**.

Для установки `MS SQL Server` требуется минимум **3.25gb ram**, хотя при работе он у меня ест не более **200** мб, на серваке же всего **500мб Ram**. Более дорогой сервер не потяну.

Посоветуйте, как поступить. Можно ли обойти это ограничение при установке? Или же лучше поменять субд? Если да, то что лучше выбрать? ('легковесное')

P.S `EF core` вроде поддерживает скажем `SQLite` и `MySQL`. Установку проводил по этой [инструкции](https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-install-sql-server-on-ubuntu/).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так вроде мсскуль может пахать внутри докера, не?

Comment: @donRumata At least 3.25 GB of RAM. Make sure to assign enough memory to the Docker VM if you're running on Docker for Mac or Windows. Это из описания Docker, тоже столько требует

Comment: Ну так-то оно так, только контейнер можно создать на одной машине, а потом перетащить на другую. Или у тебя нет поблизости компа с 4 гигами оперативы?

Comment: @donRumata неа, нету

Comment: Любопытно, как у вас EF6 работает в проекте .Net Core? Для работы проекта .Net Core надо использовать EF Core, который, к слову, как раз прекрасно работает с SQLite. Ну, или можно подключиться к PostgreSQL.

Comment: @Bulson, с EF, согласен, описался. Но на счет SQLite или других субд, это последний вариант. Меня интересует можно ли что-то сделать, чтобы установить нормально MS SQL Server, так сказать не выходя из машины, а то у меня есть проблемы с миграцией ms sql, да и времени возиться нету.

Comment: К сожалению, никак. Это следует из [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup#system). Все равно это версия для разрабов, которую запрещено использовать в продакшене.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

При размере RAM 500Mb в принципе работа SqlServer невозможна. Вот вам пример, у меня запущен сервер на виртуалке

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кроме сервера ничего более не установлено, а он уже жрет память в таком кол-ве, заметьте без нагрузки и с 5-ю копеечными тестовыми базами.

Comment: Я так понимаю, нужно менять субд? Если да, то что посоветуйте 'полегче'. Я склоняюсь к My SQL

Comment: @Xambey Для чат-бота вполне может сгодиться SQLite. Для MySQL есть вариант из двух библиотек для подключения EF Core, но я лично пока не использовал в своих проектах эту СУБД.

Comment: А насколько SQLite сложно развернуть? Я слышал что у него проблемы с развертыванием на серверах + хз, насколько хорошо поддержка его в EF Core, чтобы мне не пришлось 5к строк кода запросов через LINQ переписывать

Comment: @Xambey А что там сложного? База SQLite представляет собой один файл. Все нужное для соединения с базой устанавливается вместе с `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite` Начало работы можно с SQLite посмотреть [здесь](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/MVP-VisualStudio-Dev/EF-Core-Quick-Starts-ASPNET-Core-in-Visual-Studio-2017)

Comment: @Xambey забыл сказать, что Lazy Loading связанных таблиц не работает, нужно в запросах работать через `Include()` & `ThenInclude()`.

Comment: хм, я вроде не подгружаю нигде данные из связанных таблиц, слишком много памяти может жрать, бот и так хорошо справляется с запросами из-за параллельной обработки запросов. Спасибо, буду смотреть!)